# New Power Supply + Graphics Card and CPU upgrade

Tags: power-supply, upgrade

I have a [HP Pavillion a6500f](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01357119&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=3740339), and right now it only has stock components like a OEM 250W PSU and a onboard 128MB GeForce 7100. I plan to purchase newer, more powerful parts like:

- [Rosewill Stallion Series RD450-2-DB 450W](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817182022&cm_re=17-182-_-17-182-022-_-Product)
- [XFX Radeon HD 4670 1GB](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814150450) or a [Sapphire Radeon HD 4670 1GB](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814102855&cm_re=4670_radeon-_-14-102-855-_-Product)

  And later on, a
- [Intel Pentium Dual-Core E6500 Wolfdale 2.93GHz](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116093)

My question is, is the 450W Rosewill PSU sufficient enough to power either graphics cards and the Intel E6500 CPU?

Comment: A 450W PSU should be more than sufficient for those specifications.

Comment: They always state more than required and you said that a 400w is minimum - meaning the 450 is "more than sufficient"... I have had dual SLI systems (on lowish cards) running off of 400w psus, and that looks like a good one looking at the detailed specifications, so I stand by original statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[Newegg's Power Supply Calculator](http://educations.newegg.com/tool/psucalc/index.html)** as there are more factors to be taken into consideration than CPU and GPU.

*According to AMD the minimum [requirements for the Radeon 46xx series](http://ati.amd.com/products/Radeonhd4600/requirements.html) is a 400w PSU, with 450w you wouldn't have much reserves.*